# Ext Js Paging not works with ExtDirect Grid Panel

Tags: extjs4, gridpanel, ext-direct

Here is my thread ,i posted the actual problem of paging here in this area.
you can help me from this thread
sencha forum
[sencha forum Ext Paging problem with EXt direct Grid panel](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?281777-Ext-Js-Paging-for-Grid-panel-not-works-with-Ext-Direct&highlight=paging%20ext%20direct)

[image: First page][image: Second page]

Comment: Do you have your server side code to handle the pagination? when you click next, the grid store is called with start and limit parameters, you need to use that values to return your results from the server

Comment: Yes i get the start and limit when i apply it i get only 5 values on first load. next page is disabled

Comment: You also need to get the totalProperty, i.e total number of records you want to use for pagination. The results you return should have the count of total records, say 47 and that needs to be mapped to the proxy reader totalProperty. Let me know if you need an example

Comment: I have added a simple example as answer

Comment: but my proxy is little different i use type : 'direct', and i call via directFn

Comment: It doesn't matter you can still define a reader and try setting the totalProperty

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the answer from the forum

My Store Js

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model : 'Users',
        remoteSort : true,
        autoLoad : true,
        pageSize: 5, // items per page

        sorters : [{
            property : 'name',
            direction : 'ASC'
        }],

        proxy : {
            type : 'direct',
            directFn : 'Users.showAllUsers',
            reader: {

                    root: 'users'

            }

        }
});
```

My PHP function

```
function showAllUsers($params)
{
    $sort = $params->sort[0];
    $field = $sort->property;
    $direction = $sort->direction;
    $start = $params->start;
    $end = $params->limit;

    ($direction == 'ASC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC');

    $dbh = Dbconfig::dbconnect();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users");
    $stmt->execute();
    $number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY name $direction LIMIT $start,$end");
    $sth->execute();
    $dataAll = $sth->fetchAll();


    $data = array(
            "success" => mysql_errno() == 0,
            "total" => $number_of_rows,
            "users" => $dataAll
    );

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample on how your store and sample results should be so that your pagination works as required.

Store should look like below

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
 fields: [
     {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
     {name: 'lastName',  type: 'string'}
 ],
 proxy: {
     type: 'ajax',
     url: '/users.json',
     reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'records',
        totalProperty:  'recordCount',
        successProperty: 'success'
     }
 }
});
```

and the results from your server should be like

```
{
  recordCount: 63,
  records: [
  {
    id: 944,
    firstName: "Shannon",
    lastName: "Joy"
  },
  {
     id: 1819,
     firstName: "Remi"
     lastName: "Lucas"
  },
  .......
}
```